# What is happening with the power mode in ubuntu 21.04? Very laggy balanced mode

Tags: power-management, performance, cpu, intel-cpu

**EDIT: The actual question:**

Have you or anyone else had issues with performance degredation using this power mode on a fresh install of ubuntu 21.04. I am trying to get to the bottom of why this happened. and why I needed to install a bunch of extra tools to get my system from lagging after a fresh install.

I am actually confused as to how this tools works? I have been having issues with speed on my machine. I was trying to play some retroarch nes emulation and it was very laggy. Makes no sense since this is a farily new machine and nes emulation has been around for decades (I can emulate this on my old 333mhz psp...) so for sure my pc should be able to handle it.

I tried changing the power mode to performance. It worked much better, but its strange that the cpu freq governer wont boost the clock speed. I noticed that many things were slow including youtube. I actually wanted to know why balanced mode didnt really feel that balanced. I then did the following:
checking the governer:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Check the governer
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave

I set the governer to performance and now it looks to be working much better:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/cpufrequtils
```

and setting:

```
GOVERNOR="performance"
```

Then restarting the service

```
sudo systemctl restart cpufrequtils
```

I actually installed the cpufreq monitor: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/ and it allowed me to set the governer to performance and the power profile to balanced. Now everything seems to run smooth as butter even when the governer was set to powersave. Another thing to note is that I ran:

```
sudo sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
```

as retroach complained about performance and to consider the above code.

Why would this balanced power profile really degrade performance. I am unsure how to keep that setting. Should I just forget about it and continue to use cpufreq? Is there a consensus?

Here is my cpu info:

```
lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           142
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Stepping:                        11
CPU MHz:                         2000.000
CPU max MHz:                     4600.0000
CPU min MHz:                     400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        3999.93
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        1 MiB
L3 cache:                        8 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rd
                                 tscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts 
                                 rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperf
                                 mperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx e
                                 st tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_
                                 1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer
                                  aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowpre
                                 fetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs 
                                 ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpi
                                 d ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi
                                 2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt i
                                 ntel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm i
                                 da arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window h
                                 wp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: The actual question is have you or anyone else had issues with performance degredation using this power mode on a fresh install of ubuntu 21.04. I am trying to get to the bottom of why this happened. and why I needed to install a bunch of extra tools to get my system from lagging after a fresh install.

Comment: Then that should be the first line of the question.

Comment: @David sure, no problem. I have updated it.

Comment: You should not have needed to install a bunch of extra tools, as they merely replace primitive commands. CPU frequency scaling and power management is a complicated subject, and no one solution fits all scenarios. The answer to your question is yes, for some scenarios. We could figure out your specific conditions, but it would take some investigation.